# Keyword Selection Background?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just installed MSVS2010 Ultimate & I've noticed something which is somewhat annoying & conflicting with my syntax highlighting, as can be seen:

[alt text http://localhostr.com/files/19038c/capture.png](http://localhostr.com/files/19038c/capture.png)

As can be seen, when a keyword/function/variable/etc is highlighted all other instances of the aforementioned are highlighted too. This is somewhat annoying.

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: mirror: http://imgur.com/XUL2n.png

Answer (score 1):

This is considered a new feature of Visual Studio 2010.

But a fast trick to disable is following these steps:

> 1. Tools -> Options -> Environment ->    Font and Colors
> 2. Choose the item **Highlighted Reference**
> 3. Set its color equal to the background you are using (i suppose a 
>      really dark gray from your screenshot)

I like this feature but I tuned the color a bit to have it only little more lighter than the background :)

Answer (score 1):

When using Visual Assist, find "VA X Find Reference" in Display Items
(Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Font and Colors)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be Visual Assist X.  If you have that installed, disable "Automatically highlight references..." on the `Advanced | Refactoring` page of the VA Options dialog .

Answer (score -3):

This is a new feature from VS IDE to show you other changes tothis object. but ifyoudo not like it you can easily changed it by pressing

CTRL + ALT + Spacebar

you can read detail in [my blog](http://hajloo.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/visual-studio-2010-new-features/)

---

updtae : thismentioned in [VS2010 official Website here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465268(v=VS.100).aspx)

You also can try CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN ARROW or CTRL+SHIFT+UP ARROW. see the VS page

Comment: Just tried it, CTRL+ALT+SPACE did nothing but show the auto-complete drop-down.

Comment: I'll update my answer . you should press these whene you are opening Intellisense so check it again.

Comment: @Irwin- Do you read the instructions or not? is it really necessary to copy and paste the text in the mentioned link ?